# Xpath to get total Instagram follower count [Python, Selenium]

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, instagram

I'm putting together a Python script using Selenium that will log into Instagram (my own), and retrieve the total number of followers. I'm having trouble locating the proper Xpath element.

```
followers= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-
root"]/section/main/article/header/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span')
```

Using this Xpath turns up nothing.

Has anyone successfully done this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following xpath should work

```
followers= driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(text(), "followers")]/span')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

The following was returned:
    <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="334f4559-bd95-438d-8fd3-169858570b45", element="87e69a2a-702c-4900-a25c-151d87653685")>

Not necessarily what I was expecting; is there a way to extract the value from here?

This is the HTML I'm looking to parse:

    <span class="_fd86t" title="346">346</span>

Comment: Yon can do followers.text

Comment: Yes! Thank you, Amit! Would you happen to know how to grab the total number contained in the 'title' tag:
    <span class="_fd86t" title="10,474">10.4k</span>

Comment: `element.get_attribute("title")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this way to find number of followers :

```
followers = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-
root']/section/main/article/header/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span").text)
```